# What Database Host Entry Should be used to Install Drupal on WAMP Server?

Tags: mysql, drupal

I'm installing Drupal 7 on my Windows Server 2012 running WAMP.  Apache is listening on port 99.  I copied defaul.settings.php to settings.php and began the install process.

When I get to the database page, I enter the following in database host:

```
wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/bin/php.ini
```

I also supplied the correct MySQL credentials, created an empty Drupal database and verified that MySQL is running.

I receive the error:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host 
is known. in DatabaseConnection->__construct() (line 304 of 
C:\wamp\www\Drupal\includes\database\database.inc).
In order for Drupal to work, and to continue with the installation process, you must    
resolve all issues reported below. For more help with configuring your database server, 
see the installation handbook. If you are unsure what any of this means you should 
probably contact your hosting provider.

Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message:   
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is 
known. .
```

What must be done to get the install to talk to my database?

Comment: Why did I get -3 on this question?

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of the database configuration page and the values you are entering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you enter the path to a php configuration file as the database host? You're running MySQL on the same server, correct? Then enter *localhost* or *127.0.0.1*.

Comment: I tried localhost and also localhost:99 as that's the port on which Apache is listening. Both yield the same result.

Comment: If you're trying to connect to MySQL, why would you specify Apache's port?